# I have posted images with link as a blog post. Now I need to make the images float randomly all over the blog

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have posted images with link as a blog post. Now I need to make the images float randomly all over the blog. Is it possible? HTML code is there?

Comment: Try `images.float.randomly()`, that might work. :) I think you'll need to give a bit more detail about the desired effect, what exactly are you trying to do? Also try to fix your title when you have worked out what it is that you want.

Comment: okay.i will explain. needed just like move these images randomly just like the bubbles effect

Comment: Ok, if you add that to your post, then show what you have tried (some effort from your side, have you searched on Google?), fix your title (e.g.: "Floating bubble effect with images"), and maybe add the JavaScript and/or jQuery tags. It will give your question the right exposure and increases your chances of getting your question answered.